# Tweak RegEx code to continue to first period - even if on next line

Tags: regex

I spent half of yesterday trying various approaches found in threads here, but was unable to get something put together that worked. I'm using UiPath to read a PDF document and RegEx to grab patterns out of the resulting string. I have a code that works for 22 of my 23 cases. I have been unable to tweak the RegEx to add only the last item while maintaining only the other cases.

The problem stems from 20-02-004 - Test #4 in the link below. It contains a line break as the sentence runs into the next line in the PDF. I essentially want the RegEx to continue until the period on the next line since it hasn't bumped into it yet, but without messing up the prior matches/adding others. The 4 Test cases are the only 4 items I want the RegEx to match against from that sample.

Link below contains the input string, a sample of the string on the text tab, 4 specific test cases of what I want to match in the string on the test tab, the current RegEx I have, and the engine (JavaScript).

[Sample](http://regexr.com/579fq)

Comment: Lookbehinds are not supported by all regex engines. Please specify the platform you are using, e.g. which regex flavor. Also its unclear what you like to have as output. Adding a sample input string(s) here and expected output (or just test if match?) would be helpful.

Comment: The sample link should contain the input string, 4 specific test cases of what I want to match on the test tab, the current RegEx I have and the engine (JavaScript). I will clarify that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `(?:\n.*)?` to the regex group allows the search to run optional, additional line before matching the `[.]` at the end.

`/(?<=\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{3}\s)(.*(?:\n.*)?)([.])/g` allows the search to wrap only one additional line to find the period.

The tests pass and the text tab appears to only capture smaller more relevant matches.

Comment: Thank you, this is really close. It has the unintended consequence of grabbing 1 unwanted line, but I think I'll retest the entire 23 cases and see if maybe changing the positive lookbehind to a positive lookahead and throwing out the second occurrence of the number works.

Unwanted - 20-02-004 Status Brothers Property Management and Engineering plans to complete this
continued recommendation.

Comment: If the word `continued` at the beginning of the line is the indicator that it could should be ignored: `/(?<=\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{3}\s)(.*(?:\n(?!continued).*)?)([.])/g`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the expression to enable single line matching the `.*` matches newline characters and the tests appear to pass:

`/(?<=\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{3}\s)(.*)([.])/gs`

[image: Expression Flags]

Comment: My fault - I just noticed I never pointed out the text tab was populated. That setting does get the test to pass, but the text tab seems to capture a lot of additional lines besides just the tests.